# What are streamlines and pathlines

Tags: vector-fields, differential-equations

I asked a question earlier about having a vector field and a starting point, and then making a parametric that starts at the starting point and the derivative at any point in the parametric equals the vector field at that point. Anyway somebody mentioned streamlines and pathlines, what are they?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "Fluid Mechanics by Kundu":
"In the Eulerian description, three types of curves are commonly used to describe fluid motion: streamlines, path lines, and streak lines. These are defined and described here assuming that the fluid velocity vector, $\vec{u}$, is known at every point of space and instant of time throughout the region of interest. Streamlines, path lines, and streak lines all coincide when the flow is steady.

A streamline is a curve that is instantaneously tangent to the fluid velocity throughout the flow field. In unsteady flows the streamline pattern changes with time. In Cartesian coordinates, if $\vec{ds}=(dx, dy, dz)$  is an element of arc length along a streamline and $\vec{u} = (u, v, w)$ is the local fluid velocity vector, then the tangency requirement on $\vec{ds}$ and $\vec{u}$ leads to:

$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{v}=\frac{dz}{w}$

and $\vec{u} \times \vec{ds} = 0$
because $\vec{ds}$ and $\vec{u}$ are locally parallel.
Integrating the above equation both the upstream and downstream directions from a variety of reference locations allows streamlines to be determined throughout the flow field.

A path line is the trajectory of a fluid particle of fixed identity. It is
defined as $\vec{x} = \vec{r}(t,\vec{r}_{0},t_{0})$. The equation of the path
line for the fluid particle launched from $\vec{r}_{0}$ at $t_{0}$ is
obtained from the fluid velocity $\vec{u}$ by integrating:

$\frac{\vec{dr}}{dt}= [\vec{u}(\vec{x},t)]_{x=r}=\vec{u}(\vec{r},t)$

subject to the requirement $\vec{r}(t_{0})=\vec{r}_{0}$.

Other path lines are obtained by integrating the above equation
from different values of $\vec{r}_{0}$ or $t_{0}$. "

I will not quote the streak lines part since that you did not ask for it, but if you are interest I can add it or you can read the book.

The text is specific to fluid dynamics, but this is true for every vector field $\vec{u}$, so if you have a vector field $\vec{F}(\vec{x},t)$ and $\vec{G}(\vec{x},t)=\frac{DF}{Dt}$, where $\frac{D}{Dt}$ is the convective/material derivative, the same description applies.